# Position a link in HTML, using attributes

Tags: html, css, django, href

I am building a website, using django, CSS, HTML.
I have posted some parts from an html file I am dealing with currently.  I am a newbie in CSS/HTML. So I have problems with positioning the links which you can see below, using attributes top, left, right. The attributes margin-top, margin-left do not work either. Can you give advice on how to do this?

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}


    {% block style %}
     div{
     margin-top:1px;
     float:right
     }

    .button1{

     color:White;
     background-color:SaddleBrown;
     padding:5px;
     font-family:Comic Sans MS;
     font-size:20px;
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 12px;

     }

    {% endblock %}

{% block body %}




<a href="{%url "steak"%}" class="button1" top="100px" right="110px">STEAKS</a>
<a href="{%url "salad"%}" class="button1" top="570px" left="150px"> SALADS</a>
<a href="{%url "drink"%}" class="button1" top="830px" left="400px">DRINKS</a>





{% endblock %}
```

EDIT: the answer is the following:

```
<a href="{%url "steak"%}" class="button1" style="position:absolute; top:200px; right:190px">STEAKS</a>
<a href="{%url "salad"%}" class="button1" style="position:absolute; top:570px; left:150px"> SALADS</a>
```

I have added style attribute, position:absolute.

Comment: When using top, left, bottom or right, the elements need to be positioned anything other than static (which is the default position).  Try adding `position:relative` to your css and see if it wokrs as you want.  Also using attributes like that will not work - use css in a stylesheet or use the style attribute to set those values

Comment: Would you allow a <div> to wrap the links?  This is done so easily with one `<div>` flex-box wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you're attempting to code, and in the future you should aim to be as specific as possible. But I'm assuming you're trying to do something like this?

steak

drink

salad

First you'll need to set the display to block as links are inline elements. Then you'll need to change the position to absolute, which will remove them from the page flow. Then you can utilize top and left attributes.

```
<a href="{%url "steak"%}" class="steak-button">STEAKS</a>
<a href="{%url "salad"%}" class="salad-button"> SALADS</a>
<a href="{%url "drink"%}" class="drink-button">DRINKS</a>

.steak-button, .salad-button, .drink-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.steak-button {
  top: 100px;
  right: 110px;
}

.salad-button {
  top: 570px;
  left: 150px;
}

.drink-button {
  top: 830px;
  right: 400px;
}
```

Comment: You should also use specific class names rather than button1 so that your code is legible, easy to read, and more importantly, easy to navigate.

Comment: Besides the position attributes for the class **button 1**, I used other style features which are absolutely the same for this class. But your code does not imply using other style attributes for the same class. These links belong to the same class, and this class has the name button1! I do not need different names and different classes.

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree with this answer.

Comment: @aspiring there is no need for you to be defensive. As you explained you are new to CSS/HTML, I am giving you advice which you are free to take or ignore. You can still add whatever extra attributes you wish to the main class, I was simply answering your problem of positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
CEVAP 1

<html> 
    <head>
        <title>CSS Öğreniyorum</title>
        <style type "text/cas">
        .baslik{
        color:white;
        text-align:left;
        ornek1 { font-size:40px;
         }
    </style>
  </head>
  </body>
        <p class="ornek1">Bu paragrafta px kullanılmıştır.</p>
  </body>
<html>

 CEVAP 2

.yoghurt-button  {
   top: 110px;
   right: 150px;
}

CEVAP 3

<style>  
    div{
        color:white;
        background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, could you add some explanation as to why you think this answers the question?

Answer (score -2):

HTML elements have a `style` attribute, which allows you to write inline css on an element:

`<a href="" class="button1" style="top: 100px; right: 110px;"></a>`

HTML is used to structure the layout of your page, CSS is used to change its appearance.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/w7e2r5zg/1/

Comment: It does, though you'd require some additional styles. In order to use the `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left`properties on an element, the target element needs to have a position (ie. `position: relative`).

Comment: As I've said, this does not work at all. The links are not moved with style="top: 100px; right: 110px.

Comment: Don't be stubborn, as you've mentioned you're a newbie. I'll make an example to proof that it works :)

Comment: I've added a proof of concept, check it out.

Comment: @aspiring you appear to be ignoring my answer. Since you're unwilling to try my working answer, I wish you good luck finding a solution to your problem. Open a chat if you'd like furthur help.

Comment: I am considering your answer. It seems like you are right. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I hope you find a fitting solution :)